# looking for origin of number theory problem on 4x-floor-sqrt (maybe IMO)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

this problem was recently [posed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17417358#17417358) by [BS](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117002/balarka-sen) in the [number theory](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12070/number-theory) chat room. he thinks it may originate from the International Math Olympiad & he says he has a solution. has anyone seen it there? looking for a more precise reference/ history.

> Let $S$ be a nonempty set of positive nonzero integers such that if $x$ is in $S$ then both $4x$ and $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$ are in $S$. Prove that $S = \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: For the ones interested, here is the solution : $S$ is nonempty, thus it contains an element $x \in \Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$. Applying the second rule sufficiently many times on $x$, one can derive that $1 \in S$ as limit of the sequence $\{x^{1/2^n}\}_n$ is $1$. Using rule $1$, all the powers of $2$ are in $S$. Thus to conclude, we want to prove that for all $n$, there is some $k$ such that there exists an integer $x$ for which $2^x$ is in $[n^{2^k}, (n+1)^{2^k}]$ (for if this is true, taking roots and floors of $2^x$ for $k$ times one would eventually arrive at $n$).

Comment: This is simple enough : just cut the two ends of $[\log_2(n), \log_2(n+1)]$ off to produce an interval with rational endpoints and pick up a rational inside the interval with denominator a power of $2$. The numerator of the rational is then the desired $x$.